# MySQL Table for comments

Tags: php, mysql

This is a very amateur question (don't rate me down for it) but how would I create a column

for comments

containing the id of the post they are assigned to?

For example if I was to post a comment on post #48, how would I set that up in MySQL so the

comment shows up on post #48 and not all of the posts?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: You can't be rated down, you are at rate 1.

Comment: @ypercube i was trying to be funny lol anyways do you know how I would set that up?

Comment: How does your `posts` table look like?

Comment: Add in the description the tables you already have (at least the ones you think are relative, like `post` and `user`) and their fields.

Comment: @a1ex07 its pretty basic with 5 columns; id, title, comment, user, keywords. What kind of column would I have to add?

Comment: @ypercube what do you mean? I thought I'd have to add some relationship type of thing into mysql

Comment: @Mohamed: With `Add in the description` I meant `Add in your question above`. Sorry for the confusion. You have commented with the `post` table details, that is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a one to many relationship (one post can have many comments) so you'll be wanting a new table for it.

```
comments_tbl
 - comment_id  |   int(11) auto_increment
 - post_id     |   int(11) (FK to post table)
 - author_id   |   int(11) (FK to the user table OR author_name)
 - date        |   datetime
 - comment     |   text
```

And if you want to be able to flag and moderate comments you may wish to include something such as:

```
 - date_approved  |  datetime
 - flagged        |  int(1)
```

Your SQL then to display comments for a post would be like

```
mysql_query("SELECT comment_id, author_name, comment FROM comments_tbl WHERE post_id = '$postid' AND date_approved IS NOT NULL AND flagged = '0'");
```

To add a comment to the database:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (post_id, author_id, date, comment) VALUES ('$postid', '$author_id', '$date', '$comment');
```

Comment: No problem, just noticed your comment above about adding to the table to included a demo INSERT .. please remember to clean the variables before inserting using `mysql_real_escape_string` or even better use prepared statements such as `pdo` and `mysqli`

Answer (score 6):

You don't create a *column* for comments, but a new *table*.

simply,

```
table Post
id,
content

table Comment
id,
content,
post_id
```

Where post_id is a reference to the id of the post.

Comment: I know but how would i be able to display comments to the specific post it was intended for?

Comment: @Mohamed Yusuf. Well, it depends how you have done. If you have a specific post you just do `select * from Comment WHERE post_id = 'the post id'`

Comment: lets say they were on the page for post #50. How would i be able to have the users post comments to only post 50

Comment: @Mohamed Yusuf. Then you just insert a new row to the Comment table, where you set the post_id to the id of the post that a user has posted to. This requires you to include the id of the post in a hidden field(if you are using forms).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to do in PHP code is to store in a variable ID of the post the comment is assigned to (for example `$postId`. Then you can insert comment into **new** table somewhow like this (I'm not writing table structure, hope you will see it from the query):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (id_post, text) VALUES ('".$postId."', 'Text of the comment'");
```

When you want to select it, you will use this query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT text FROM comments WHERE id_post = '".$postId."'");
```

By the way, the `id_post` column is called *foreign key* ane there should be defined index for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table for your posts, you will need a new table for your comments. To associate comments with posts, just make a `post_id` column in your comments table.

```
comments
- comment_id int(8) Auto_Increment 
- post_id int(8)
- comment_author varchar(255)
- comment_content text()
```

`post_id` should be the ID of the post that you are associating the comment in, where each comment gets it's own row in this table. If your authors can be associated by an ID that is better, just change the `varchar(255)` to `int(8)` or something that fits in with the rest of your design.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (id int unsigned not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
post_id int unsigned not NULL,
// other fields, post_date, post_text, etc
FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Note : `FOREIGN KEY` are supported by `INNODB` engine, so if your table is `MyISAM`, you don't need it.  `post_id` must have the same type as primary key in `posts` - I assumed `post.id` is unsigned integer.